# Matplotlib plotting an undefined number of axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am reading an excel sheet and generating a numpy array (data_array)
In this array each row is a different group (for example: dogs, cats, birds, insects, etc... the number of items will depend on each excel sheet)
The columns are fixed to 9 elements for each group (age, color, etc)

Now I can graph plot each row. In this example I am only plotting the element 7 of the data_Array.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x,y = data_array.shape

ind = np.arange(y)  
width = 1

rects = ax.bar(ind, data_array[7], width, color='r')

plt.xticks(ind, names, rotation=90)
plt.ylabel('Area')
plt.title('Normalized IS')          
plt.show()
```

I could write:

```
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, data_array[1], width, color='r')
rects2 = ax.bar(ind, data_array[2], width, color='r')
.
.
.
rectsx = ax.bar(ind, data_array[x], width, color='r')
```

Then I could plot all of them in the same chart.
However, each excel I am reading have a different x number of elements.

I thought about genereting them using:

```
for i in range(x):
    rects[i] = ax.bar(ind, data_array[i], width, color='r')
```

but I got an error message.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       rects[1]=ax.bar(ind, data_array[7], width, color='r') NameError: name 'rects' is not defined

How to generate each ax.bar?

Comment: "but I got an error message" is not useful. You need to include the complete error traceback if you want help with that. Also you should not use `...` when asking about a code - how should anyone know what `..` is and whether or not it causes the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use a loop,

```
for i in range(x):
    ax.bar(ind, data_array[i], width, color='r')
```

This would plot all bars from different rows on top of each other.

Comment: Thanks, that help a lot. however, I only see one plot. Are one on the other I only see the overlay?

Comment: Yes, they are on top of each other. You need to describe accurately how you want the plot to look, if you're not happy with that.